# Как взаимодействовать в потоке с Edit`ами и Memo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Учусь программировать. Работаю в Delphi 6. Не могу разобраться с потоками. Типичная ситуация, когда UI не отвечает на какие-либо манипуляции с формой при обработке большого файла. Проблема заключается в том, что реализация костыльная. Когда пытаюсь создать поток, то появляется ошибка  "Undeclared identifier: 'Edit1'" и Memo1 соответственно.

Кратко о программе.

На входе есть данные, которые помещаются в Memo1, в этих данных я ищу строки в определенном формате и с ними произвожтекст, выделенный жирным шрифтому манипуляции, при этом записывая их в Memo2. В итоге получается в Memo2 облее 2 млн. строк. Через кнопку произвожу сохранение.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы реализовать работу программы без зависания UI.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, FileCtrl;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    OpenDialog1: TOpenDialog;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Button3: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
    Button4: TButton;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Public declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  position : Integer;
  line, column, str, temp, convert : Integer;
  flag : boolean;
  counter : Integer;
  memes2, iter, rep : Longint;
  template, perevod : String;
  circl : String;
  saveDialog1 : TSaveDialog;
  fname:string;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
       if OpenDialog1.Execute then
       Memo1.Clear;
       Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
       Button2.Enabled:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
        Form1.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
        saveDialog1 := TSaveDialog.Create(self);

  // Give the dialog a title
  saveDialog1.Title := 'Save your text or txt file';

  // Установка начального каталога
  saveDialog1.InitialDir := GetCurrentDir;

  // Разрешаем сохранять файлы типа .txt и .vec
  saveDialog1.Filter := 'Text file|*.txt|Vec file|*.vec';

  // Установка расширения по умолчанию
  saveDialog1.DefaultExt := 'txt';

  // Выбор текстовых файлов как стартовый тип фильтра
  saveDialog1.FilterIndex := 1;

  // Отображение диалог сохранения файла
  if saveDialog1.Execute then
  fname:=savedialog1.FileName;
  memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(fname);
  ShowMessage('File : '+ saveDialog1.FileName);


  // Освобождения диалога
  saveDialog1.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
        str:= 0;
        edit1.Clear;
        edit2.Clear;
        Memo2.Clear;
        iter:= 0;
        counter:= 0;
        for line:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
                begin
                     for column:=1 to length(Memo1.lines[line]) do
                        begin
                               if (Memo1.Lines[line][1] = ' ') or (Memo1.Lines[line][1] = '=') or (Memo1.Lines[line][1] = '/') or (Memo1.Lines[line][1] = 'n') then break;
                               if (Memo1.Lines[line][column] <> ' ') then counter:= 1 + counter;
                               if (column = 7) and (counter = 7) then
                                begin
                                        for column:= 7 to length(Memo1.lines[line]) do
                                                begin
                                                     if Memo1.Lines[line][column] = ':' then str:= column;
                                                     if Memo1.Lines[line][column] = ' ' then begin rep:= column; break; end;
                                                end;

                                          if str = 0 then     // Печатаем строки без повторения
                                                begin
                                                     for temp:= 1 to rep - 1 do
                                                        begin
                                                                edit1.text:=  edit1.text + Memo1.Lines[line][temp] ;
                                                        end;
                                                        perevod:= Format('%.7d', [iter]);
                                                        Memo2.Lines.Add(perevod + ' ' + edit1.text);
                                                        iter:= iter + 1;
                                                        edit1.Clear;
                                                end;
                                          if (str <> 0) and (rep <> 0) then // Вычисляем количество повторений строк и переводим в Integer
                                                begin
                                                        for temp:= str + 1 to rep - 1 do
                                                                begin
                                                                        edit2.text:=  edit2.text + Memo1.Lines[line][temp] ;
                                                                end;
                                                convert:= StrToInt(edit2.text);
                                                edit2.Clear;
                                                end;
                                          if str <> 0 then   //  Печатаем строки с повторениями
                                                begin
                                                    for temp:= 1 to str - 1 do
                                                        begin
                                                                edit1.text:=  edit1.text + Memo1.Lines[line][temp] ;
                                                        end;
                                                    for temp:= 1 to convert do
                                                        begin

                                                                 perevod:= Format('%.7d', [iter]);
                                                                 Memo2.Lines.Add(perevod + ' ' + edit1.text);
                                                                 iter:= iter + 1;

                                                        end;
                                                        edit1.Clear;


                                                end;

                                        str:= 0;
                                        column:= 0;
                                end;
                        end;

                        counter:= 0;
                end;
        end;

end.
```

Comment: Если вы работаете в Делфи 6, то зачем на вопросе метка [delphi-7]?

Comment: @Kromster Метки d6 вроде нет, а d7 даёт представление об имеющихся инструментах.

Comment: @MBo теперь есть )

Comment: @Kromster Да какой смысл? ;)

Comment: @MBo всё конечно тлен, если глобально подходить. Но в целом версия есть, вопросы по ней могут быть. Пускай будет.

Comment: @Kromster У меня такие соображения - изо всей "классики" имеет смысл использовать только семёрку, остальное в малых количествах существует. Различия внутри этой группы на сегодняшний момент кажутся уже незначительными по сравнению с отличиями от юникодных, фымыиксных, 64-разрядных, а конкретные детали уже в тексте можно отметить, чтобы не плодить метки (25 штук)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз строк у Вас много, то `Memo`, скорее всего, вообще не нужны - незачем хранить кучу данных в визуальном компоненте.

Загрузите файл в `TStringList` и спокойненько обрабатывайте, результат можно сложить в другой `TStringList`.

`Edit.Text` тоже ни к чему, он используется только как строка - так и возьмите строку.

Возможно, вам вообще будет достаточно без потока обработать данные - без обращения к визуальным контролам всё пройдет в сто раз быстрее.

Все эти манипуляции можно делать в дополнительном потоке, если операция действительно длительная - опишите наследника `TThread`, создайте его экземпляр, передайте ему имя файла и какие там ещё нужны данные для обработки,  запустите поток в работу. В функции `Execute` сделайте всё, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

В каждом цикле for перед end; напиши application.processmessages;
Должно полегчать.